# Redirection rule in Outlook.com to Salesforce issue

Tags: apex-email-service

I have a website which has a contact form. The form is sent to a outlook.com email. And in this outlook.com account I have a redirection rule configured to redirect to an apex email service. The funny thing is, sometimes the redirection works perfect but sometimes it does not work (I monitored in salesforce as well and I have no reception of email). But in those cases If the automatic redirections fails, I do a manual redirection, and the email is received. Does anyone experienced a similar situation between outlook.com redirections with salesforce? Is there something related to outlook.com or salesforce?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally we found an issue related to the apex email service (Actually with a duplicate rule). The debugging is hard in this contexts.